# I can not click on an element that is inside a ComboBox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got the contents of a list (ul) using xpath and put it in a variable of type List . Then I looped the variable elements and had them print the contents of the list.

The eclipse displayed the list with all the options contained in the list (li). Inside the loop I made an IF to look for the GEOCF option and, if it is found, the script will click. Even the GEOCF option exists, I can not click on it and the routine goes to the ELSE.

It follows the source code and the print of the images.

```
public void selecionarAuditoriaNacional() throws Exception {

    WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.id("consultarUnidadeAuditoria"));
    findElement.click();

    List<WebElement> elementos = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper']/ul"));

    for (WebElement elementosGrid : elementos) {

        System.out.println(elementosGrid.getText());

        if (elementosGrid.equals("GEOCF")) {

            elementosGrid.click();

        } else {

            System.out.println("Erro");

        }

    }

}
```

[image: ComboBox]

[image: Console Eclipse]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GEOCF is a list element and reside in the li tag. But you are getting all  `ul` tag in your elements list.

Change the xpath locator to find `li` and one typo in if condition changed `elementosGrid.equals("GEOCF")` to `elementosGrid.getText().equals("GEOCF")`

```
List<WebElement> elementos = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper']/ul/li"));

for (WebElement elementosGrid : elementos) {

    System.out.println(elementosGrid.getText());

    if (elementosGrid.getText().equals("GEOCF")) {

        elementosGrid.click();

    } else {

        System.out.println("Erro");

    }

}
```

Or

you can remove the entire loop & if and handle find element with text with single xpath

```
public void selecionarAuditoriaNacional() throws Exception {

  WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.id("consultarUnidadeAuditoria"));
  findElement.click();

  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait (driver, 60);
  elementosGrid=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.VisibilityofElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class = 'ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper']/ul/li[text() = 'GEOFC']")));
  elementosGrid.click()
}
```